# Track the changes done in database Schema

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a database  with 100 + tables and 50+ views.
Each table got multiple columns with different type of possible constraints.
I have a build x.1 as a baseline for above database.
I need to know the way where I can generate the current DB structure in text file so that I can compare it with future DB structure to track the changes.

DB is SQL Server 2008 R2
I have SQL Server Management Studio to analyse it.
I have tried using the option Task --> Generate  Script and it gives me the sql script to generate database but I want output like all the table names and then each table structure in text format so that I can use tools like winmerge for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to track changes in a database. I would consider changing tool. Here is a list of real good database compare tools:

- [dbForge Schema Compare](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/schemacompare/)
- [SQLDBTools](http://sqldbtools.com/)
- [Redgate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/)
- [Apex sql](http://www.apexsql.com/default.aspx)

My personal favorite is Apex sql. A really nice tool where you can do nice diffs and scripting databases to other versions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is worth considering a scheduled process that uses a schema comparison tool to check against a snapshot or a scripts folder in source control. Grant Fritchey has written an article that you could use as a basis for implementing this:

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/auditing-ddl-changes-in-sql-server-databases/